# Codeigniter - How to share model between Two Applications

Tags: codeigniter

I have two applications in codeigniter. Called App1 and App2 under application folder. i have created two App1.php and App2.php for application. Now i want to share MODEL of the App1 in App2 and vice-versa. Can you please tell me how i can share model and also library of App1 in App2 and vice-versa???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Application "Packages"
>
> An application package allows for the easy distribution of complete
>   sets of resources in a single directory, complete with its own
>   libraries, models, helpers, config, and language files. It is
>   recommended that these packages be placed in the
>   application/third_party folder. Below is a sample map of an package
>   directory

Look in the user's guide "loader class" for more info on them.

Comment: URL for @MikeCruz's answer:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html